# Spring Boot ファイルアップロードしたCSVを保存せずにデータを読み取るとファイルがロックされたままになる

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Bootを使用してCSVファイルをアップロードして、データを取り込む機能を実装しております。
ファイルアップロードしたCSVからデータを読み取るとファイルがロックされたままの状態になり、エディタから編集することができませんでした。
Chromeでは発生しなかったのですが、FirefoxとIEで発生しているようです。解決する方法はあるのでしょうか。

おそらくStream周りが原因かと思いますので、データ取得のメソッドを添付します。

■データ取得メソッド

```
public List<List<String>> getCsvData(MultipartFile csvFile) throws Exception {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    
    InputStream stream = null;
    Reader reader = null;
    BufferedReader buf = null;
    try {
        stream = csvFile.getInputStream();
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        buf= new BufferedReader(reader);
        while((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        line = buf.readLine();
        
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) stream.close();
        if (reader != null) reader.close();
        if (buf != null) buf.close();
    }
    if(0 < lines.size()) lines.remove(0); 
    
    List<List<String>> csvData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (String lineDat : lines) {
        List<String> splited = this.csvSplit(lineDat);
        csvData.add(splited);
    }
    
    return csvData;
}
```

Comment: ちょっと奇妙な動作に感じるので正しく事実を認識したいのですが、「ロックされたままになるファイル」というのはアップロード対象のファイルで、ブラウザが動作しているクライアントにあるもの、という認識で良いでしょうか。また、ファイルロックしているプロセスを特定するツールがいくつか存在していますが(例: [MS公式ツール Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer))、こういったもので誰が実際にファイルをロックしているかを、事象が発生している環境で調べることはできるでしょうか(例えば、実はファイルロックしていたのはアンチウイルスソフトだった、みたいな想定外のものだったりすることもあり得るかな、と)。

Comment: @出羽和之　クライアントにあるファイルがロックされます。 ご教示いただいたツールを使用してロックしているプロセスを確認してみましたが検出されませんでした。その後の調査で分かったことですが、ファイルロックの警告は特定のテキストエディタでのみ発生していたようです。Windowsのメモ帳とExcelでの編集は問題なく行えたのでユーザにはそちらを使うようにお願いしました。エディタの不具合として解決にしようと思います。